# C# Linq Convert Object Property to Array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an object that I am converting to JSON to be consumed by Ember.js.
Currently I have some child objects that are fully expanded but ember expects
just an array of ids on the client side. How can I flatten the object out to
be a `int[]`

```
items = Mapper.Map<IList<Item>>(client.GetItems());
foreach (var item in items)
{
  int[] choices = item.Choices.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();

  item.Choices = choices;
}
```

get an error about not being able to convert to type `int[]` from `IList<Item>`
how can I cast the property?

example current JSON I produce after serializing

```
{ "items": [
   {
     "id": 0,
     "name": "Item0",
     "description": "...",
     "choices": [
       { "id": 0, "property": "somevalue" },
       { "id": 1, "property": "somevalue" },
     ]
   },
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Item1",
     "description": "...",
     "choices": [
       { "id": 0, "property": "somevalue" },
       { "id": 1, "property": "somevalue" },
     ]
   }
]}
```

The JSON I would like to produce

```
{ "items": [
   {
     "id": 0,
     "name": "Item0",
     "description": "...",
     "choices": [0, 1]
   },
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Item1",
     "description": "...",
     "choices": [0, 1]
   }
]}
```

Comment: Issue is here: item.Choices = choices; item.Choices is of type List and you are trying to assign choices of type int[].

Comment: Yea how can I get around that without creating a completely new class with the only difference that Items is an int[] instead of an IList<>. I want to change the type of that property for this instance of the object.

Comment: Why don't use SelectMany?

Comment: You don't need to create another class and you cannot change the property type. You can create another property of int[] type in the existing class and use the linq statement in the getter. Something like item.ChoiceIDs?

Comment: `SelectMany` is not going to help you here. You need to make a new class with choices defined as `int[]` instead of `IList<Item>`

Answer (score 4):

`SelectMany` flattens List of Lists and produces single List with all items.

```
items.SelectMany(x=>x.Choices.Select(y=>y.Id).ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

> get an error about not being able to convert to type int[] from IList how can I cast the property?

You cannot cast one type to another. Instead you can create another property of type int[] in your class and use the LINQ statement in getter (with necessary validation checks).

```
public int[] ChoiceIDs
{ 
    get {
     return this.Choices.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
    }
}
```